# iOS - Pagination using a Dictionary based UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dictionary, pagination

I'm building an iOS application which has a tableview with multiple sections.

The sections depends on the number of keys on an NSMutableDictionary.

I'm trying to make pagination by adding data to that dictionary every time I reach the last cell of the row.

My problem is that the pagination event is fired multiple times and makes the sections look in different order. I guess the last problem is because of the method I'm using to add new data is `addEntriesFromDictionary`.

So basically my questions are:
- Is the Dictionary data source approach a proper one? Should I change it for an Array data source one?
- Causes of the multiple pagination calls issue

Here's my code so far:

```
@implementation FooViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.FooStore = [[FooStore alloc]init];
    [self.FooStore getFooDTO: @1];
    [self setNavigationBar:nil];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleFooDTOChange:)
                                                 name:@"FooDTOChanged"
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleLoadDataFoo:)
                                                 name:@"loadDataFoo"
                                               object:nil];

    self.activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                             initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:    UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];


    self.activityView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.activityView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:self.activityView];

}


- (void)handleFooDTOChange:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *theData = [note userInfo];
    if (theData != nil) {
        FooDTO *FooDTO = theData[@"FooDTO"];
        if(FooDTO.date != nil){
            [self setNavigationBar:FooDTO.date];
            [self.activityView stopAnimating];
        }

    }
}

- (void)handleLoadDataFoo:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *theData = [note userInfo];
    if (theData != nil) {
        [self.FooStore getFooDTO: theData[@"paginaActual"]];
    }
}

… some code ..


@end
```

Table View Controller:

```
@implementation FooTableViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.currentPage = 1;
    self.data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleFooDTOChange:)
                                                 name:@"FooDTOChanged"
                                               object:nil];


}


- (void)handleFooDTOChange:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *theData = [note userInfo];
    if (theData != nil) {
        FooDTO *FooDTO = theData[@"FooDTO"];
        if ([[FooDTO.dataFoo allKeys] count] > 0){
            [self.data addEntriesFromDictionary: FooDTO.dataFoo];
            [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return self.data.allKeys.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSString *arrayKey = [self.data.allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *a = [self.data objectForKey:arrayKey];

    return a.count;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *arrayKey = [self.data.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *dataKey = [self.data objectForKey:arrayKey];

    if(indexPath.row == [dataKey count] -1 && indexPath.section == [self.data.allKeys count] - 1){
        self.currentPage++;
        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = @{
                                         @"currentPage": [NSNumber numberWithInt: self.currentPage]
                                        };
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loaddataFoo" object:self userInfo:dataDictionary];
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@implementation FooStore

- (FooDTO *) getFooDTO: (NSNumber *) page
{

    FooDTO *FooDTO =[[FooDTO alloc]init];


    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSString *dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                //urlparameters
                                 };

    [manager POST:@"http://my.service/foos.json" parameters:parameters
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //handle data
              }


              NSDictionary *dataDictionary = @{
                                               @"FooDTO": FooDTO
                                               };

              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FooDTOChanged" object:self userInfo:dataDictionary];
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
              NSDictionary *dataDictionary = @{
                                               @"error": error
                                               };


              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FooError" object:self userInfo:dataDictionary];
          }
    ];

    return nil;
};

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered collections. The sections and rows in a table view must be served up in the same order every time the table view asks for information, so dictionaries are not suitable.

It's pretty common to use a single NSArray or NSMutableArray for a single-section table view, or an array of arrays for a multi-sectioned table view. (The outer array contains your sections and the inner arrays contain the rows for each section.

You can make the data for each cell a dictionary if that's helpful (So you would have an array of arrays of dictionaries.) That way each key/value pair in the inner dictionary contains different information that you need to display in your cells.

I would suggest NOT using a dictionary to represent the cell in your table view. (But as noted you CAN use a dictionary to save the different settings for a cell.)